# How to stop an overflowing span from clipping off another span

Tags: html, css

So I have 2 words in spans within a fixed width div. Currently, I'm using text-overflow: ellipsis to clip them.  But if the first word is really long, it pushes and clips the second word.

So it looks like this:

|Word 1 Word 2 |

and when I have a long first word it cuts off word 2 like this:

| ReallyLongW...|

How can I get it so Word 2 doesn't get cut off, and instead Word 1 does like this:

| Reall... Word 2|

I feel like there's definitely some combination of css and containers to get this done, but I haven't found it yet. Note that I still want Word 2 left aligned and appended to the end of Word 1 like before, just the overflow behavior should change.

Edit: This is the closest I've gotten

```css
.mydiv {
    max-width: 150px;
}

.myspan {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    color: #f00;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myotherspan { 
    float: left;
    color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
   <span class="myspan">Wordaksjdkajsdasfasdfds</span>
   <span class="myotherspan">Word 2</span>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
   <span class="myspan">Word 1</span>
   <span class="myotherspan">Word 2</span>
</div>
```

This will work well enough for me because in my case, I know Word 2 will always be small and around the same size (4-7ish characters).  But ideally I don't want to hardcode the the max width because I don't want to hardcode it to the worst case 7 characters, then waste whitespace when it turns out to only be 4 characters. I'd rather it dynamically size Word 1 to fit what ever is there after Word 2 fits in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.mydiv {
    max-width: 100px;
}

.myspan {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    color: #f00;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myotherspan { 
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
   <span class="myspan">Wordaksjdkajsd</span>
   <span class="myotherspan">Word 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's closer than I've gotten, but not quite it.  If Word 1 is short, then Word 2 only floats to the center, not all the way to Word 1.